# SP2013 - The object is used in the context different from the one associated with the object

Tags: client-object-model, spcontext

I have a function that initializes a custom taxonomy control, as below (not in `myControl.js`)

```
function initMyControl() {
    if (something is true) {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
        $(controlId).myControl({ arrayOfOptions }, context);
    }
}
```

Inside `myControl.js` I save the context in a global variable when I extend jQuery

```
$.fn.myControl = function (options, ctx) {
    spContext = ctx;
}
```

I use `spContext` in several places in my javascript code, but when I come to an execution of where I want execute a query in relation to my control, I hit the `Exception` in the title.

```
this.NewTerm = parent.createTerm(label, myControl.LCID, id);
spContext.load(this.NewTerm);
spContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(myControl, myControl.termAddSuccess),
    Function.createDelegate(myControl, myControl.termAddFailed));
```

When I try to run `executeQueryAsync` I get the exception
`Sys.InvalidOperationException: The object is used in the context different from the one associated with the object`, even though the context is the same.

How come this is happening, and what is a possible workaround?

Comment: This is a late reply. Just want to know your findings on this. I too have come across this error with CSOM C#, whenever i try to use client object in different context than it's associated with. My understanding is any single client object(LisItem,User etc) is associated with only the clientcontext it's loaded from and it's not supposed to be used in different context(e.g Update a client object from different context). In your case, you said you are using only one context. That makes me suspicious and proves my understanding on this exception incorrect. Can you please confirm if you got the er